# Select files from Assets folder with prefix

Tags: android, file, filter, directory

Why is `secondaryImages = null` after the operation?
I guarantee in the `/assets/forms/` folder there are multiple files starting with `eq01008`.

```
    private static final String mFormsDirectory = "forms";
    String[] secondaryImages;
    File dir = new File("file:///android_asset/" + mFormsDirectory);
    secondaryImages = dir.list(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.startsWith("eq01008");
        }
    });
```

Update:
This also returns NULL for `secondaryImages`:

```
    File dir = new File("file:///android_asset");
    // Also tried: File dir = new File("file:///android_asset/");
    String[] secondaryImages = dir.list();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
 String[] secondaryImages = new String[size];
```

looks like your not initialising secondaryImages

It might be better to use and array list of type String if you dont know the size.

```
 ArrayList<Sring> secondaryImages = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Doesn't matter about initializing it, because I am completely setting it to something new. I cannot use ArrayList because `File.list()` returns `String[]`. The issue is not syntactical. Thanks for replying though.